# Get selected form when drop down option changed

Tags: php, jquery, forms, drop-down-menu, netbeans-8

I want to have selected form when i choose the different drop down option. 
- Having to choose what their occupation are and based on that, different form options will be flashed out. Here is my codes thus far. Please advice thanks.

```
<script>
$('#casualties-Form').change(function(){
    if ($(this).val() == "Student") {
        $('#Staff').hide();
        $('#Student').show();
    } else {
        $('#Staff').show();
        $('#Student').hide();
    }
});
</script>

<form id="casualties-Form" name="casualtiesForm" method="post" action="doCasualtiesForm.php">
<legend><b><u>CASUALTIES SUMMARY CHART</u></b></legend>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><label for="form">Casualty:</label></td>
        <td>
            <select id="myselect" name="myselect">
                <option value="Student">Student</option>
                <option value="Staff">Staff</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <form name="Student" id="Student" class="hidden">
    <tr>
        <td width="150px"><label for="date">Date:</label></td>
        <td><input type="date" id="date" name="Date"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label for="time">Time:</label></td>
        <td><input type="time" id="time" name="Time"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ID:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="ID"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label for="School">School</label></td>
        <td>
            <select>
                <optgroup label="ss" name="School"> 
                </optgroup>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Status:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="Status"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label for="Location">aaa</label></td>
        <td>
            <select id="Location" name="Location">
            <option>aaa </option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Lecturer Contact No:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="Number"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label for="NOK_informed">NOK Informed:</label></td>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" id="NOK_informed" name="NOK" value="Yes" title="Yes"/>Yes
            <input type="radio" id="NOK_informed" name="NOK" value="No" /> No
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <!--/* to let the submit button to be under the fields */-->
        <td></td>
        <td>
        <input name="btnsubmit" value="Submit" type="submit"></p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </form> <!--/* This is Student Form */-->
</table>
<form name="Staff" id="Staff" class="hidden">
<table>    
    <tr>
        <td width="150px"><label for="date">Date:</label></td>
        <td><input type="date" id="date" name="Date"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label for="time">Time:</label></td>
        <td><input type="time" id="time" name="Time"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ID:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="ID"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label for="Department">Department</label></td>
        <td>
            <select id="Department" name="Department">
                <option>bbb</option>
            </select>
        </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>Status:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="Status"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label for="Location">Hospital</label></td>
        <td>
            <select id="Location" name="Location">
                <option>ccc</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Officer Contact No:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="Number"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label for="NOK_informed">NOK Informed:</label></td>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" id="NOK_informed" name="NOK" value="Yes" title="Yes"/>Yes
            <input type="radio" id="NOK_informed" name="NOK" value="No" /> No
        </td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
            <!--/* to let the submit button to be under the fields */-->
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <input name="btnsubmit" value="Submit" type="submit"></p>            
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form> <!--/* This is Staff Form */-->
```

Comment: So, when the user chooses student, it should show the student form, and when they click staff, it should show staff?

Comment: Yes. I've managed to appear the student form out. But somehow the Staff form din managed to change upon selected Staff.

Answer (score 3):

I changed your code slightly, and this works just fine:

JSFiddle: [Click](http://jsfiddle.net/wz2p0e1s/2/).

Also make sure to use

```
$(document).ready(function(){

});
```

Please note that I also changed the way your form is, so you don't have a form in a form.

**Code HTML:**

```
<legend><b><u>CASUALTIES SUMMARY CHART</u></b>
</legend>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label for="form">Casualty:</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select id="myselect" name="myselect">
                <option value="Student">Student</option>
                <option value="Staff">Staff</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div id="studentForm">
    <form id="casualties-Form" name="casualtiesForm" method="post" action="doCasualtiesForm.php">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td width="150px">
                    <label for="date">Date:</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="date" id="date" name="Date" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="time">Time:</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="time" id="time" name="Time" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>ID:</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="ID">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="School">School</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select>
                        <optgroup label="ss" name="School"></optgroup>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Status:</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="Status">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="Location">aaa</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select id="Location" name="Location">
                        <option>aaa</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Lecturer Contact No:</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="Number">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="NOK_informed">NOK Informed:</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" id="NOK_informed" name="NOK" value="Yes" title="Yes" />Yes
                    <input type="radio" id="NOK_informed" name="NOK" value="No" />No</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <center>
                        <input name="btnsubmit" value="Submit" type="submit">
                    </center>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</div>
<div id="staffForm">
    <form id="casualties-Form" name="casualtiesForm" method="post" action="doCasualtiesForm.php">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td width="150px">
                    <label for="date">Date:</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="date" id="date" name="Date" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="time">Time:</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="time" id="time" name="Time" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>ID:</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="ID">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="Department">Department</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select id="Department" name="Department">
                        <option>bbb</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Status:</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="Status">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="Location">Hospital</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select id="Location" name="Location">
                        <option>ccc</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Officer Contact No:</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="Number">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="NOK_informed">NOK Informed:</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" id="NOK_informed" name="NOK" value="Yes" title="Yes" />Yes
                    <input type="radio" id="NOK_informed" name="NOK" value="No" />No</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <center>
                        <input name="btnsubmit" value="Submit" type="submit">
                    </center>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</div>
```

**Code JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myselect').change(function(){
            if ($(this).val() === "Student") {
                    $('#staffForm').hide();
                    $('#studentForm').show();
            } else {
                    $('#studentForm').hide();
                    $('#staffForm').show();
            }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you can use onchange event on select

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#myselect").change(function(){
    selVal = $(this).val();
    $(".form-holder").slideUp("fast",function(){

        $("#"+selVal).slideDown("fast");
    });
});
});

<legend><b><u>CASUALTIES SUMMARY CHART</u></b></legend>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="form">Casualty:</label></td>
            <td><select id="myselect" name="myselect" >
                <option value="Student">Student</option>
                <option value="Staff">Staff</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan='2'>
            <div class='form-holder' id='Student'>
                <form name="Student" >
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td width="150px">
                                <label for="date">Date:</label></td>
                            <td><input type="date" id="date" name="Date"/></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><label for="time">Time:</label></td>
                            <td><input type="time" id="time" name="Time"/></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>ID:</td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="ID"></td>
                                </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><label for="School">School</label></td>
                                <td><select>
                                    <optgroup label="ss" name="School"> 
                                    </optgroup>
                                    </select>                                    
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Status:</td>
                                <td><input type="text" name="Status"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><label for="Location">aaa</label></td>
                                <td><select id="Location" name="Location">
                                    <option>aaa </option>
                                    </select>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Lecturer Contact No:</td>
                                <td><input type="text" name="Number"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><label for="NOK_informed">NOK Informed:</label></td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="radio" id="NOK_informed" name="NOK" value="Yes" title="Yes"/>Yes
                                    <input type="radio" id="NOK_informed" name="NOK" value="No" /> No
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                                    <!--/* to let the submit button to be under the fields */-->
                                <td></td>
                                <td>
                                    <input name="btnsubmit" value="Submit" type="submit"></p>
                                </td>
                             </tr>
                       </table>

                     </form> <!--/* This is Student Form */-->
                    </div>
                        </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan='2'>
<div class='form-holder' id='Staff' style='display:none;'>
                                    <form name="Staff">
                                        <table>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td width="150px"><label for="date">Date:</label></td>
                                                <td><input type="date" id="date" name="Date"/></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td><label for="time">Time:</label></td>
                                                <td><input type="time" id="time" name="Time"/></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>ID:</td>
                                                <td><input type="text" name="ID"></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td><label for="Department">Department</label></td>
                                                <td><select id="Department" name="Department">
                                                        <option>bbb</option>
                                                    </select>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>Status:</td>
                                                <td><input type="text" name="Status"></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td><label for="Location">Hospital</label></td>
                                                <td><select id="Location" name="Location">
                                                        <option>ccc</option>
                                                    </select>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>Officer Contact No:</td>
                                                <td><input type="text" name="Number"></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td><label for="NOK_informed">NOK Informed:</label></td>
                                                <td><input type="radio" id="NOK_informed" name="NOK" value="Yes" title="Yes"/>Yes
                                                    <input type="radio" id="NOK_informed" name="NOK" value="No" /> No
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <!--/* to let the submit button to be under the fields */-->
                                                <td></td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <input name="btnsubmit" value="Submit" type="submit"></p>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </form> <!--/* This is Staff Form */-->
</div>
                                            </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

And here is your [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6yayycek/)

Comment: I tried both method. But it's still can't work for me. After making the changes, these are my current codes.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>RP Crisis Management</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
    <table align="center" >
        <td width="70%" height="122"><img src="LOGO.PNG" width="350" height="130" alt="left" /></td>
        <td width="30%"><img src="RP_Logo.gif" alt="" width="316" height="119" align="right" /></td>
        <tr>
            <td width="75%" align="center" valign="top" style="background-position: left top; 
                background-repeat: no-repeat;"><marquee class="GeneratedMarquee" direction="left" scrollamount="9" behavior="scroll" onmouseover="this.stop();" onmouseout="this.start();">
            *Important Message!: </marquee></td>
    <td rowspan="2">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#myselect').change(function() {
                    if ($(this).val() === "Student") {
                        $('#staffForm').hide();
                        $('#studentForm').show();
                    } else {
                        $('#studentForm').hide();
                        $('#staffForm').show();
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
        <h3><a href = "loginSuccess2.html">Home</a> | <a href = "logout.html"> Log Out </h3></a>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><h3>Welcome, BCM/CEP Taskforce </h3></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td height="133" colspan="2">
        <table width="100%" border="0">
            <tr>
                <td width="10%" valign="top">
                    <table width="100%" height="203" border="0" style="border: thin solid #000;">
                        <tr>
                            <td height="26" valign="top" style="border: thin none #000; padding: 5px; margin: 5px; color: #FFF; background-color: #6fb01e; font-weight: bold; font-size: 14px; font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;">Navigation Bar</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <b><u>Track Incident</u></b><br/>
                                <a href = "BCM.html">View Incident (BCM)</a><br/>
                                <a href = "CEP.html">View Incident (CEP)</a><br/>
                                <br/>
                                <b><u>Maintenance</u></b><br/>
                                <a href = "addIncident.html">Add Incident</a><br/>
                                <a href= "addOpsLogForm.html">Add Operation Log</a><br/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td><!-- /* The above code is for the Navigation Bar */ -->
                <td width="50%" valign="top">
                    <table width="100%" height="auto" border="0" style="border: thin solid #000;">
                        <tr>
                            <td height="26" valign="top" style="border: thin none #000; padding: 5px; margin: 5px; color: #FFF; background-color: #6fb01e; font-weight: bold; font-size: 14px; font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;">Add Casualties</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                        <legend><b><u>CASUALTIES SUMMARY CHART</u></b>

                        </legend>
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <label for="form">Casualty:</label>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <select id="myselect" name="myselect">
                                        <option value="Student">Student</option>
                                        <option value="Staff">Staff</option>
                                    </select>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        <div id="studentForm">
                            <form id="casualties-Form" name="casualtiesForm" method="post" action="doCasualtiesForm.php">
                                <table>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td width="150px">
                                            <label for="date">Date:</label>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <input type="date" id="date" name="Date" />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <label for="time">Time:</label>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <input type="time" id="time" name="Time" />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Student ID:</td>
                                        <td>
                                            <input type="text" name="ID">
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <label for="School">School</label>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <select>
                                                <optgroup label="SOI" name="School">
                                                    <option>Diploma in Business Applications</option>
                                                    <option>Diploma in Business Information Systems</option>
                                                    <option>Diploma in Information Technology</option>
                                                    <option>Diploma in Interactive and Digital Media</option>
                                                    <option>Diploma in IT Service Management</option>
                                                    <option>Diploma in Mobile Software Development</option>
                                                    <option>Diploma in Infocomm Security Management</option>
                                                    <option>Specialist Diploma in Mobile Applications</option>
                                                    <option>Specialist Diploma in Business Analytics</option>
                                                </optgroup>
                                                <optgroup label="SOH" name="School">
                                                    <option>Diploma in Integrated Events Management</option>
                                                    <option>Diploma in Customer Experience Management with Business</option>
                                                    <option>Diploma in Hotel and Hospitality Management</option>
                                                    <option>Diploma in Wellness, Lifestyle and Spa Management</option>
                                                    <option>Diploma in Restaurant and Culinary Operations</option>
                                                </optgroup>
                                                <optgroup label="SAS" name="School">
                                                    <option>Diploma in Marine Science and Aquaculture</option>
                                                    <option>Diploma in Biomedical Sciences</option>
                                                    <option>Diploma in Biotechnology</option>
                                                    <option>Diploma in Materials Science</option>
                                                    <option>Diploma in Pharmaceutical Sciences</option>
                                                    <option>Diploma in Environmental Science</option>
                                                </optgroup>
                                                <optgroup label="SEG" name="School">
                                                    <option>Diploma in Aerospace Avionics</option>
                                                    <option>Diploma in Aerospace Engineering</option>
                                                    <option>Diploma in Aviation Management</option>
                                                    <option>Diploma in Electrical and Electronic Engineering</option>
                                                    <option>Diploma in Engineering Systems and Management</option>
                                                    <option>Diploma in Engineering Design with Business</option>
                                                    <option>Diploma in Green Building Energy Management</option>
                                                    <option>Diploma in Industrial and Operations Management</option>
                                                    <option>Diploma in Supply Chain Management</option>
                                                </optgroup>
                                                <optgroup label="SHL" name="School">
                                                    <option>Diploma in Health Management and Promotion</option>
                                                    <option>Diploma in Health Services Management</option>
                                                    <option>Diploma in Outdoor and Adventure Learning</option>
                                                    <option>Diploma in Sports and Exercise Sciences</option>
                                                    <option>Diploma in Sports and Leisure Management</option>
                                                    <option>Diploma in Sports Coaching</option>
                                                </optgroup>
                                                <optgroup label="STA" name="School">
                                                    <option>Diploma in Arts and Theatre Management</option>
                                                    <option>Diploma in Design for User Experience</option>
                                                    <option>Diploma in Game Design</option>
                                                    <option>Diploma in Media Production and Design</option>
                                                    <option>Diploma in Sonic Arts</option>
                                                </optgroup>
                                            </select>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Status:</td>
                                        <td>
                                            <input type="text" name="Status">
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <label for="Location">Hospital</label>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <select id="Location" name="Location">
                                                <option>Alexandra Hospital</option>
                                                <option>Changi General Hospital</option>
                                                <option>Ng Teng Fong General Hospital</option>
                                                <option>SengKang Health</option>
                                                <option>National University Hospital</option>
                                                <option>Khoo Teck Puat Hospital</option>
                                                <option>Singapore General Hospital</option>
                                                <option>Tan Tock Seng Hospital</option>
                                                <option>KK Women's and Children's Hospital</option>
                                            </select>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Lecturer Contact No:</td>
                                        <td>
                                            <input type="text" name="Number">
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <label for="NOK_informed">NOK Informed:</label>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <input type="radio" id="NOK_informed" name="NOK" value="Yes" title="Yes" />Yes
                                            <input type="radio" id="NOK_informed" name="NOK" value="No" />No</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td colspan="2">
                                    <center>
                                        <input name="btnsubmit" value="Submit" type="submit">
                                    </center>
                                    </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                        <div id="staffForm">
                            <form id="casualties-Form" name="casualtiesForm" method="post" action="doCasualtiesForm.php">
                                <table>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td width="150px">
                                            <label for="date">Date:</label>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <input type="date" id="date" name="Date" />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <label for="time">Time:</label>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <input type="time" id="time" name="Time" />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Staff ID:</td>
                                        <td>
                                            <input type="text" name="ID">
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <label for="Department">Department</label>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <select id="Department" name="Department">
                                                <option>ACE@RP</option>
                                                <option>COI-SCM</option>
                                                <option>Centre for Educational Development</option>
                                                <option>Centre for Enterprise and Communication</option>
                                                <option>Logistics Project Office</option>
                                                <option>Office of Academic Services</option>
                                                <option>Office of Corporate Communications</option>
                                                <option>Office of Estates</option>
                                                <option>Office of Human Resources</option>
                                                <option>Office for Finance</option>
                                                <option>Office for Industry and Collaboration</option>
                                                <option>Office of Information Services</option>
                                                <option>Office of International Relations</option>
                                                <option>Office of Organisation & Service Excellence</option>
                                                <option>Office of Planning</option>
                                                <option>Office of Procurement & Business Continuity</option>
                                                <option>Office for Student and Graduate Affairs</option>
                                                <option>Office of Technology Development</option>
                                                <option>Office of Registrar</option>
                                                <option>Principal's Office</option>
                                                <option>School of Applied Science</option>
                                                <option>School of Engineering</option>
                                                <option>School of Hospitality</option>
                                                <option>School of Infocomm</option>
                                                <option>School of Sports, Health and Leisure</option>
                                                <option>School of Technology for the Arts</option>
                                                <option>SkillsFuture Office</option>
                                            </select>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Status:</td>
                                        <td>
                                            <input type="text" name="Status">
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <label for="Location">Hospital</label>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <select id="Location" name="Location">
                                                <option>Alexandra Hospital</option>
                                                <option>Changi General Hospital</option>
                                                <option>Ng Teng Fong General Hospital</option>
                                                <option>SengKang Health</option>
                                                <option>National University Hospital</option>
                                                <option>Khoo Teck Puat Hospital</option>
                                                <option>Singapore General Hospital</option>
                                                <option>Tan Tock Seng Hospital</option>
                                                <option>KK Women's and Children's Hospital</option>
                                            </select>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>CARE Officer Contact No:</td>
                                        <td>
                                            <input type="text" name="Number">
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <label for="NOK_informed">NOK Informed:</label>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <input type="radio" id="NOK_informed" name="NOK" value="Yes" title="Yes" />Yes
                                            <input type="radio" id="NOK_informed" name="NOK" value="No" />No</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td colspan="2">
                                    <center>
                                        <input name="btnsubmit" value="Submit" type="submit">
                                    </center>
                                    </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Include jquery.js.
You need to attach change event to your dropdown. So this
   >>  $('#casualties-Form').change(function() 
should be 
  >>   $('#myselect').change(function()